# How to number custom table of contents with css?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am currently dynamically creating a table of contents based on my HTML using Javascript.

One of the options I want to give users, when they create their table of contents, is whether they want to use the numbering created in my **JS** or **CSS** numbering.

My *JS* numbering works fine however my *CSS* numbering does **not**.
Because I am not using `ol` *or* `li` to create my list, it makes it very hard to select and number my table with CSS.

I have included a picture of what my table looks like in the dev console. As you can see each item has a class *toc-level* and then a *number*.

The *"main-headings"* would have level 1 and with the *"sub-headings"* being level 2 etc. I tried using CSS counters to perform this task but I'm not exactly sure how to implement it correctly. I would like the numbering to go **1**, **1.1**, **1.2**, **1.2.1** etc. for the *"mainheadings"* and *"subheadings"*.

Does anyone have any Ideas how to do this?

[image: My Code from the Dev Console]

Thanks a lot.

UPDATE:

I found this CSS that helps but it is unable to number sub-sub headings like my level 3 headings:

```
.show-css-numbering {
        counter-reset: heading;
    }

    .toc-level-1:before {
        content: counter(heading)") ";
        counter-increment: heading;
    }

    .toc-level-1 {
        counter-reset: subheading;
    }

    .toc-level-2:before {
        content: counter(heading)"." counter(subheading)") ";
        counter-increment: subheading;
    }
```

Comment: something like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/cristiannn/g38ynvko/32/

Comment: @CananauCristian Unfortunately it has to be in CSS though. My javascript numbering works. But thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following format of css to answer my question:

```
   .show-css-numbering {
            counter-reset: heading;
        }

        .toc-level-1:before {
            content: counter(heading)") ";
            counter-increment: heading;
        }

        .toc-level-1 {
            counter-reset: subheadingLVL2;
        }

        .toc-level-2:before {
            content: counter(heading)"." counter(subheadingLVL2)") ";
            counter-increment: subheadingLVL2;
        }

        .toc-level-2 {
            counter-reset: subheadingLVL3;
        }

        .toc-level-3:before {
            content: counter(heading)"." counter(subheadingLVL2)"." counter(subheadingLVL3)") ";
            counter-increment: subheadingLVL3;
        }

        .toc-level-3 {
            counter-reset: subheadingLVL4;
        }

        .toc-level-4:before {
            content: counter(heading)"." counter(subheadingLVL2)"." counter(subheadingLVL3)"." counter(subheadingLVL4)") ";
            counter-increment: subheadingLVL4;
        }

        .toc-level-4 {
            counter-reset: subheadingLVL5;
        }

        .toc-level-5 {
            content: counter(heading)"." counter(subheadingLVL2)"." counter(subheadingLVL3)"." counter(subheadingLVL4)"." counter(subheadingLVL5)") ";
            counter-increment: subheadingLVL5;
        }

        .toc-level-5 {
            counter-reset: subheadingLVL6;
        }

        .toc-level-6 {
            content: counter(heading)"." counter(subheadingLVL2)"." counter(subheadingLVL3)"." counter(subheadingLVL4)"." counter(subheadingLVL5)"." counter(subheadingLVL6)") ";
            counter-increment: subheadingLVL6;
        }
```

This resulted in a list with correctly numbered sub-headings and headings. All the way up to sub-heading level 6. Afterwards you can also include the `.show-css-numbering` in front of all the selectors so that the numbering can be turned on and off with Jquery as needed.